# Как передать переменную в из одной стр в другую, с закрытием первой?

Tags: php, javascript, popup

Все здравствуйте! Не пинайте, учусь )
Возникла необходимость передать переменную php из открытого popup окна в форму на родительскую страницу с последующим авто закрытием popup окна. Направьте пожалуйста на путь истинный ) Спасибо!

Comment: почему не сделать все на javascript???

Answer (score 1):

Просто с php не получится, надо использовать JS.Есть несколько вариантов,простой пример если не страшны параметры GET:
код в файле popup

```
<script type=""text/javascript>
window.close();
window.opener.location.href="http://vashsite.ru?yourkey=<?php echo $php_var;?>";
</script>
```